# What the following code represent?

Tags: javascript

```
const getActions = () => [
  require('./add'),
  require('./sub'),
  require('./mul'),
  require('./div')
];
module.exports = (func, actions= getActions());
```

In the above code, we added four require statements inside []. What exactly this means?
Again we are calling the same function getActions()  in module.exports.

Could anyone explain what is the basic of this syntax and its purpose?

Comment: Kindly look at the [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: getActions would be a function with an array of modules loaded by require(route).
Module.exports finally would be composed by getActions() results. I don't get why is ther "func" becaouse in a 'tuple' the result should be only the rightmost instruction output.

Answer (score 2):

The first part defines a function assigned to the constant `getActions`. The function is a *concise arrow function* returning an array containing the results of calling `require` four times. (`[]` is an array initializer.)

The second part (the exports part) is using the comma operator to evaluate the `func` identifier (note that it's not calling it, there are no `()`; which is a bit odd), then to call `getActions` and assign its result to `actions`. The result is also then assigned to `module.exports` since the result of an assignment is the value assigned, and the result of the comma operator is the value resulting from evaluating its right-hand operand.

So for instance, other than the `const` bit, here's that with an old-style `function` and without the comma operator, broken into its parts (but retaining the order):

```
function getActions() {
    return [/*...the four require calls here...*/];
}
func;
actions = getActions();
module.exports = actions;
```